# How to exchange data between a Windows Desktop application (C# ASP.net) and a Web Application(C# ASP.net) being run in its embedded Browser Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, desktop-application

I have a web application written in C# ASP.net(ASP.net 3.5) hosted on an IIS 7 server. Presently a client Windows Desktop Application(ASP.net 4.6.2) is under development that requires to run this Web Application on a client PC inside a an **embedded Browser Control**.It is required that, on the client, on click of a button inside web application, files/data are communicated to the client Desktop Application which processes and then saves them on the local computer , while simultaneously sending confirmation to the server.

What is the manner in which this communication between the Client Desktop Application and the Web application inside its Browser control can be achieved. Please provide some direction. Searching on the internet is not helping much.

Comment: The web browser is just much of a client as your Desktop application. The communication can be acheived through a RESTful API. The question is how do you want to handle it. One option is to have the API hosted on local host (IIS) with your Desktop client https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/ and the web application can call that API however you want.

Comment: @Phael Umm.. I think the question is not clear.I've edited it - Please have a look again. The Desktop application is on the client and it has to receive certain data from the web application opened inside its embedded browser. How does it receive that data.